# Exit from nested Navigation Graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have 3 graphs: 'Main', '1', and '2'

App starts to 'Main', we check if user is logged in, then we go to either '1' or '2' depending on logged in state.

This works as expected.

Here's the issue:

When the user clicks 'back' from the '1' or '2' main screen, the app navigates back to 'Main'.

Here's the expected result:

When the user clicks 'back' from the '1' or '2' main screen, the app should exit.

**How do I exit from the top level fragment of a nested graph?**

Here's my 'Main' navigation graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_main_to_logged_out_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/logged_out_navigation"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_navigation"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_main_to_logged_in_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/logged_in_navigation"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_navigation"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/logged_in_navigation" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/logged_out_navigation" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Does user navigate to `1` or `2` graphs from the main screen of  `Main` graph? If so going back to main screen of `Main` is expected

Comment: Does the following answer fix your issue?

Comment: This is intended behavior and won't be fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140124444

Comment: @zoha131 nuts.  Post that as an answer and I'll give you the check mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing the same issue. After some google, I have found an issue on the Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140124444

It says, This is intended behavior and won't be fixed. And As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you should not be popping the start destination off your back stack.

Answer (score 3):

Inorder to exit app when in a nested nav graph destination just use `popUpTo` and set it to   `main_nav_graph.xml`

**Example:**

**Design**

[image: main nav graph]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation ...
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/start">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:name="com.example.navargs.StartFragment"
        android:label="Start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start" >
        ...
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_start_to_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/login_nav_graph"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/main_nav_graph.xml" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment ... />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/login_nav_graph" />
</navigation>
```

For a working example checkout [login-flow branch](https://github.com/kaushalyap/so-navargs/tree/login-flow) in the repo.

Comment: I'm already doing this and, unfortunately, it's not doing the trick

Comment: It does work in the repo though. Try deleting that action and recreating. Also try changing nav version to latest

Comment: the repo has nested navigation elements, not 'include' elements.  I suspect it doesn't work the same with 'include' elements but hoping I'm just doing something wrong

Comment: @Psest328 if you can setup a sample repo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user158 the repo doesn't work for me. In the fragment called First, if you click the up navigation button then the app does not close. Instead, come to the first page again.

Comment: @zoha131 checkout login-flow branch not the default repo

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [user158](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7356355/user158) answer, to get out of the application from a nested navigation, you must configure popUpTo and popUpToInclusive.

Example:

- Line 14 and 15 of the following image [main_navigation.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV5Ad.png)

main_navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFragment"
        android:name="com.fortatic.apps.nestednavigationexample.start.StartFragment"
        android:label="fragment_start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_navGraphOne"
            app:destination="@id/navGraphOne"
            app:popUpTo="@id/startFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_navGraphTwo"
            app:destination="@id/navGraphTwo"
            app:popUpTo="@id/startFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navGraphOne"
        app:startDestination="@id/AFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/AFragment"
            android:name="com.fortatic.apps.nestednavigationexample.one.AFragment"
            android:label="fragment_a"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_AFragment_to_BFragment"
                app:destination="@id/BFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/AFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/BFragment"
            android:name="com.fortatic.apps.nestednavigationexample.one.BFragment"
            android:label="fragment_b"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
    </navigation>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navGraphTwo"
        app:startDestination="@id/CFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/CFragment"
            android:name="com.fortatic.apps.nestednavigationexample.two.CFragment"
            android:label="fragment_c"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_CFragment_to_DFragment"
                app:destination="@id/DFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/DFragment"
            android:name="com.fortatic.apps.nestednavigationexample.two.DFragment"
            android:label="fragment_d"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_d" />
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

You can also check the source code on [github](https://github.com/AlejandroFortt/NestedNavigationExample/tree/nested-navigation)

Comment: Indeed, there are 2 branches, one in which i show how to generate a nested navigation graph (branch [nested-navigation](https://github.com/cforta/NestedNavigationExample/tree/nested-navigation)) and another in which i show how to do the same but integrating ViewModels (branch [nested-navigation-with-viewmodels](https://github.com/cforta/NestedNavigationExample/tree/nested-navigation-with-viewmodels)).
You can see the one you need.

Comment: you have 1 navhostfragment not 2. You have 2 navigation graphs but you doenst need them at all.

Comment: Correct, I have only 1 navhostfragment, as the user who asked the question, and i have 3 navigation graphs and if i need them, I need them to be in the same situation as the one who asked the question.
I have a main graph and 2 nested graphs, just as the question says.